# How do I merge two heads of a branch on Bitbucket?

Tags: branch, mercurial, bitbucket

I'm not terribly familiar with Mercurial, and I have no idea how I managed to do this in the first place...

https://bitbucket.org/agent154/controlsfx/branch/wizard-before_advance?head=d6dda855fd9885d3413121068e73c0fa73e3cc2e

See above link. My branch "wizard-before_advance" has multiple heads. I've been doing development using IntelliJ IDEA, but I have TortoiseHG installed. How might I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably did was make two separate commits with revision `22ec847` as the parent. This might have occurred in two separate clones, where you committed and pushed both of them to bitbucket (expect you'd have needed a `-f` on the second one). It could also have occurred in a single clone because you updated to an old version and committed there.

Regardless, it's not a problem. All you have to do is merge them. The message tells you which two revisions to work with.

```
d6dda85
2d5a883
```

So we `update` to one of these, and merge the other.

```
% hg update -r 2d5a883 
% hg merge -r d6dda85
<Run checks, resolve conflicts, and basically make sure everything is good>
% hg commit -m 'Merging divergent heads'
```

This will leave you with a graph like this:

```
o---o---o---------M---
     \           /
      \-o---o---o
```

Where M is the merge change-set. Simple